# How to prove that every negative value is an eigenvalue for T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the linear space of all functions continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and such that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^x tf(t) \,dt$ exists for all real $x$. If $f\in V$ let $g=T(f)$ be defined by the equation $g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x tf(t) \,dt$. Prove that every negative $\lambda$ is and eigenvalue for $T$ and determine the eigenfunctions corresponding to $\lambda$.

My problem is mostly with the proof part. I'm rather new to linear algebra so please do not be stingy on the details.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For $\lambda<0$ you need to solve the integral equation

$$\int_{-\infty}^x t f(t) dt=\lambda f(x)$$

I suggest you differentiate first and look at the resulting differential equation. Then maybe a g(a)u(e)ss helps..

Comment: Why are you supposing the $\lambda<0$?I mean, we don't know from the outset that $\lambda<0$. That's what we're trying to prove. I have already solved the integral equation. What I don't know is how to show that **every** $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue!

Comment: Yes, for every negative $\lambda$ there is an equation which you need to solve and you get an eigenfunction for that particular $\lambda$ proving that it is an eigenvalue.

Comment: Then is it correct to say that we also have an eigenfunction for every positive $\lambda$ as well?

Comment: No. These functions will not lie in the space $V$ (why?).

Comment: The answer to the integral equation is $Ce^{x/\lambda}$ and if $\lambda>0$ the the integral does not exist since it is from infinity. So $\lambda<0$. If what I just said is correct, then we're done and I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: Correct, for $\lambda\ge 0$ the integrals $\int^x_{-\infty} t e^{t/\lambda} dt$ do not exist.